# How to check if application is in foreground cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I work in Ionic Application, where I need to open a specific page in the app when users tap on notification,

Code

```
       push.on('notification', function(data) {
            window.plugins.toast.showShortTop('You have received a new Application!');
            window.location.hash = 'home/contactus';
        });
```

Its work fine when an application start open first time. But the problem is that when application open and that time user get any notification application redirect to **'home/contactus'** page every time.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the push plugin raises the notification event when the notification is received and again when it's clicked.
Your best bet is to assign and track the ids of notifications sent to the app:

```
var receivedNotifications={};
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    if(!receivedNotifications[id]){
        receivedNotifications[id]=true;
        return;
}
        window.plugins.toast.showShortTop('You have received a new Application!');
        window.location.hash = 'home/contactus';
    });
```